# How to add marking in bar chart using d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

I need to create a bar chart using d3 with some highlighting between the starting & ending points(like a marker). Here's my code snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Simple Bar chart</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
        }
        
        .bar {
            fill: #5f89ad;
        }
         .highlight {
            fill: #ff0;
        }
        .axis {
            font-size: 13px;
        }
        
        .axis path,
        .axis line {
            fill: none;
            display: none;
        }
        
        .label {
            font-size: 13px;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="graphic"></div>

    <script>
        var data = [{
                "name": "Case 01",
                "value": 2000,
                "xValue": 500,
                "slength": 100,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 02",
                "value": 1290,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 03",
                "value": 19000,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 04",
                "value": 5000,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 05",
                "value": 1600,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 06",
                "value": 2600,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 07",
                "value": 3000,
        },
 {
                "name": "Case 08",
                "value": 7000,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 09",
                "value": 3290,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 10",
                "value": 12000,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 11",
                "value": 10000,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 12",
                "value": 11600,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 13",
                "value": 5600,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 14",
                "value": 6000,
        },{
                "name": "Case 15",
                "value": 8600,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 16",
                "value": 4280,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 17",
                "value": 9000,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 18",
                "value": 5000,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 19",
                "value": 4300,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 20",
                "value": 2600,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 21",
                "value": 6700,
        },{
                "name": "Case 22",
                "value": 12000,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 23",
                "value": 8290,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 24",
                "value": 8000,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 25",
                "value": 7600,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 26",
                "value": 1600,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 27",
                "value": 5500,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 28",
                "value": 4400,
        },{
                "name": "Case 29",
                "value": 8900,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 30",
                "value": 6790,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 31",
                "value": 11000,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 32",
                "value": 5000,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 33",
                "value": 6600,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 34",
                "value": 7700,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 35",
                "value": 3000,
        }];

        //sort bars based on value
        data = data.sort(function (a, b) {
            return d3.descending(a.name, b.name);
        })

        //set up SVG using margin conventions - we'll need plenty of room on the left for labels
        var margin = {
            top: 15,
            right: 100,
            bottom: 15,
            left: 100
        };

        var width = window.innerWidth  - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = window.innerHeight- margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var svg = d3.select("#graphic").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        var x = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([0, width])
            .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
                return d.value;
            })]);

        var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .rangeRoundBands([height, 0], .1)
            .domain(data.map(function (d) {
                return d.name;
            }));

        //make y axis to show bar names
        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            //no tick marks
            .tickSize(0)
            .orient("left");

        var gy = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis)

        var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("g")

        //append rects
        bars.append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("y", function (d) {
                return y(d.name);
            })
            .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("width", function (d) {
                return x(d.value);
            })
        //add a value label to the right of each bar
        bars.append("text")
            .attr("class", "label")
            //y position of the label is halfway down the bar
            .attr("y", function (d) {
                return y(d.name) + y.rangeBand() / 2 + 4;
            })
            //x position is 3 pixels to the right of the bar
            .attr("x", function (d) {
                return x(d.value);
            })
            .style('fill', 'darkGray')
            .text(function (d) {
                return d.value;
            });
        
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

In this, I need to add a marker similar to this image[image: Required implementation]

Thought of using the Stacked Bar chart, but it won't be working in this case as the behind line gives the whole value and the highlighted color gives the searched term in that document and it may repeat few times for the same line.

Comment: Add a second set of bars for the markers and use the xScale to determine the `x` and `width` of the rect based on marker-start-end values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a second set of bars and assign the `x` and `width` based on marker's start and end points.

Assuming `xValue` to be the starting point and `slength` being the width of the highlight, here's the relevant code to add the markers:

```
// add markers
bars.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "highlight")
    .attr("y", function (d) {
        return y(d.name);
    })
    .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
    .attr("x", function (d) {
        return x(d.xValue);
    })
    .attr("width", function (d) {
        return x(d.xValue + d.slength);
    });
```

**Code snippet (including the highlights within a couple more rows):**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Simple Bar chart</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
        }
        
        .bar {
            fill: #5f89ad;
        }
         .highlight {
            fill: #ff0;
        }
        .axis {
            font-size: 13px;
        }
        
        .axis path,
        .axis line {
            fill: none;
            display: none;
        }
        
        .label {
            font-size: 13px;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="graphic"></div>

    <script>
        var data = [{
                "name": "Case 01",
                "value": 2000,
                "xValue": 500,
                "slength": 100,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 02",
                "value": 1290,
                "xValue": 300,
                "slength": 50,
      },
            {
                "name": "Case 03",
                "value": 19000,
                "xValue": 1000,
                "slength": 300,
      },
            {
                "name": "Case 04",
                "value": 5000,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 05",
                "value": 1600,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 06",
                "value": 2600,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 07",
                "value": 3000,
        },
 {
                "name": "Case 08",
                "value": 7000,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 09",
                "value": 3290,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 10",
                "value": 12000,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 11",
                "value": 10000,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 12",
                "value": 11600,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 13",
                "value": 5600,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 14",
                "value": 6000,
        },{
                "name": "Case 15",
                "value": 8600,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 16",
                "value": 4280,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 17",
                "value": 9000,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 18",
                "value": 5000,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 19",
                "value": 4300,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 20",
                "value": 2600,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 21",
                "value": 6700,
        },{
                "name": "Case 22",
                "value": 12000,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 23",
                "value": 8290,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 24",
                "value": 8000,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 25",
                "value": 7600,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 26",
                "value": 1600,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 27",
                "value": 5500,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 28",
                "value": 4400,
        },{
                "name": "Case 29",
                "value": 8900,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 30",
                "value": 6790,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 31",
                "value": 11000,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 32",
                "value": 5000,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 33",
                "value": 6600,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 34",
                "value": 7700,
        },
            {
                "name": "Case 35",
                "value": 3000,
        }];

        //sort bars based on value
        data = data.sort(function (a, b) {
            return d3.descending(a.name, b.name);
        })

        //set up SVG using margin conventions - we'll need plenty of room on the left for labels
        var margin = {
            top: 15,
            right: 100,
            bottom: 15,
            left: 100
        };

        var width = window.innerWidth  - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = window.innerHeight- margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var svg = d3.select("#graphic").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        var x = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([0, width])
            .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
                return d.value;
            })]);

        var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .rangeRoundBands([height, 0], .1)
            .domain(data.map(function (d) {
                return d.name;
            }));

        //make y axis to show bar names
        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            //no tick marks
            .tickSize(0)
            .orient("left");

        var gy = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis)

        var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("g")

        //append rects
        bars.append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("y", function (d) {
                return y(d.name);
            })
            .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("width", function (d) {
                return x(d.value);
            })
        //add a value label to the right of each bar
        bars.append("text")
            .attr("class", "label")
            //y position of the label is halfway down the bar
            .attr("y", function (d) {
                return y(d.name) + y.rangeBand() / 2 + 4;
            })
            //x position is 3 pixels to the right of the bar
            .attr("x", function (d) {
                return x(d.value);
            })
            .style('fill', 'darkGray')
            .text(function (d) {
                return d.value;
            });

    // add markers
        bars.append("rect")
            .attr("class", "highlight")
            .attr("y", function (d) {
                return y(d.name);
            })
            .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
            .attr("x", function (d) {
             return x(d.xValue);
            })
            .attr("width", function (d) {
                return x(d.xValue + d.slength);
            })        
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

And a fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/wc4q3r1y/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Shashank this is what I'm looking for.